Prisma Postgres: Query using model but with extensions and custom operators
Here I want to use the extension pgtrm for postgres for string matching.
Example without extension
select * from user where name = 'jon'; -- <none>

Example with extension
select * from user where name % 'jon'; -- John, Johnathan, Bon Jovi, ...

The equivalent prisma syntax would be 
Example without extension
const result = await prisma.userDb.findMany({ where : { name : 'jon' } })


??
Ideally I would want to use it in this way if possible
Example with extension
const result = await prisma.userDb.findMany({ where : { name : Prisma.sql` % 'jon'` } })

Is there a way to query using the model syntax and custom operators?
I know its possible using below raw statement, but would like to use the model syntax
const result = await prisma.$executeRaw(Prisma.sql`select * from user where name % 'jon'`);

